# Next or previous item in Angular2 Firebase based on current key

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the key of an item in firebase in my photo gallery and want to go to the next or previous picture when the user press the buttons. Outside Angular2 I would expect that I can do something like this to get the next.

```
ref.orderByKey().startAt(lastKnownKey).limitToFirst(1);
```

However,

1. How can I implement this in Angular2 Firebase
2. How can I go to the previous element instead of the next?

Edit: My Angular2 implementation:

```
 public getPhotoForKey(key: string): FirebaseObjectObservable<IPhoto> {
    window['af'] = this.af.database.list(`list`, {
      query: {
        orderByKey: true,
        startsAt: key,
        limitToFirst: 2
      }

    });
```

Comment: The query you build looks fine. What's the problem?

Comment: Hi Frank. I added my Angular2 implementation above. However, I'm not sure 1) How to get the previous item instead of the next item and 2) How to just return an object instead of getting 2 items and then taking the last (the first item in the list I'm returning is the item corresponding to the input key)

Comment: The next element works as intended. However, I still haven't been able to figure out how to get to the previous element in Firebase

Comment: `endAt: key, limitToLast: 2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frank's suggestion works:

endAt: key, limitToLast: 2